# How to know Window user detail logged in Unix server using putty

Tags: unix

I have one common user named **meduser** in unix **SunOS** server, many people logged into the same user **meduser** from Window machine using putty.

Please reply me if there is any way to know the Windows user detail currently logged in the Unix server.

Comment: Why not having one account per user, so you can managed who is doing what ?

Comment: Username is meduser.  Is this a medical environment in U.S.A.?  If so, HIPAA rules state that each user must have a unique login.  I imagine other regions may have the same rules.   I recommend the answer @peterh supplied below.

Answer (score 2):

If all users login with the same Unix user/password, you don't get any information about the Windows user.

If you have enough control over the Windows machines to get login logs, you can try to correlate between originating IP address of the connection and looking up who as logged into that machine at the time of the connection. This isn't reliable though and will not work if more than one user is logged into the Windows machine (e.g. at a terminal server).

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are going about this the wrong way. A user should always authenticate as himself. You should never allow user accounts where many people have the password. In particular on Solaris (I would say moreso than compared to Linux and Windows) there are multiple ways to avoid this.

At our site we have our Solaris boxes integrated with AD so people log into Solaris as themselves (i.e. as their Windows identity). However once inside you'll often see them `su`-ing into a role, e.g. `meduser`. Even if they have su'ed to something else we can always track what their ultimate identity is.

If you are not familiar with the concept of roles on Solaris then now is the time to familiarize yourself.

Answer (score 0):

On your Solaris box the `last` command will tell you who is logged in and from where as well as other information that may be useful.

You can use the hostname information to work out what the remote machine is. By configuring suitable logging on the remote machine you can correlate who was logged in when the connection was made to the solaris box.

A better solution would be to give everyone their own login and then do what's necessary to get them using the application correctly.